# Why does Ethernet stop working if the value of Ethernet DMA control registers refers to CCM memory?

Tags: stm32, ethernet, dma, keil, linker

### Development environment and application details

I'm working with STM32F427 and I use **Keil uVision V5.29** to develop my application. The version of the ArmCLang Compiler, of the Assembler and the linker is **6.131.1**.

In the project I'm using Azure ThreadX (core version 6.1.10.) The project uses much memory resources (more than 100 Kbytes only for the buffers used by the thread pools) so the linker selects the 64 KBytes of CCM memory (core coupled memory) to allocate some program variables.

### Problem description

By means of many empirical attempts I have seen that when the value contained in some DMA control registers (for example the **DMATDLAR** register) is between the addresses from 0x10000000 to 0x10010000 the Ethernet stops working. **This addresses area is used to map CCM memory**.

### Modification of the scatter file

To solve the problem I have excluded the CCM memory by using the following scatter file:

```C
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00030000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

The original scatter file was:

```C
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00030000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
  RW_IRAM2 0x10000000 0x00010000  {
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

### Question

Does anyone know why if the value of some Ethernet DMA control registers refers to CCM causes Ethernet to stop working?

Comment: Further to justme’s answer, this separation of memories is fairly common on a number of similar devices. Reason being high bandwidth peripherals like enet and USB can get high priority access without contending with the cpu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CCM memory is not in the list of supported DMA memory targets for Ethernet. Or any other DMA access.

The CCM is not part of bus matrix and can only be accessed by CPU.

Comment: Thanks very much. With your info I have understand something more of the STM32 manual. I have found the **Application Note 4296 of ST** that speaks about this topic.